# Redshift: Any difference in performance between # and temporary tables?

Tags: query-performance, aws, redshift, compression, encoding

Is there any difference between the below two styles of using temporary tables in Redshift -- in terms of cluster performance (or) R/W into and from the table?

I am new to Redshift, hence bit unaware of the column compression (encodings) and how it affects query/cluster performance.

On Redshift version -

> PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2
> 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.52931

Please advise, and help to learn. Much appreciated. :)

```
-- Query 1 -- 
SELECT...INTO #tmp_t WHERE...;
```

or

```
-- Query 2 -- 
CREATE TEMPORARY tmp_t (
     . . . 
     . . .
);
INSERT INTO tmp_t SELECT ...;
```